# dojo pass URL parameter into AJAX

Tags: ajax, dojo

I want to take URL parameter and pass to ajax function,

```
    var queryParams = dojo.queryToObject(window.location.search.slice(1));
    var data = dojo.toJson(queryParams, true);
     console.log(data);
    getCategory( data );
...
function getCategory(input){


    dojo.xhrGet( {
            // The following URL must match that used to test the server.
            url: "http://js.localhost/dojo-release-1.5.0-src/json3.php",
            handleAs: "json",
            content: input,
```

on my URL parametetr, I pass in

> ?return_type=category&category_desc=Business2

when I view on firebug, the ajax request become ....

> t?0=%7B&1=%0A&2=%09&3......

but data debug is correct, any idea what's wrong?

> { "return_type": "category",
>   "category_desc": "Business2" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found out that it doesn't need dojo.toJson

```
var queryParams = dojo.queryToObject(window.location.search.slice(1));
getCategory(  queryParams );
```